# Getting following error "org.neo4j.kernel.api.exceptions.TransactionFailureException: Transaction rolled back even if marked as successful" at neo4j

Tags: java, neo4j, graph-databases

Wrote stored proc in neo4j and then added it in the neo4j plugins. When calling the stored proc getting the error"

> org.neo4j.kernel.api.exceptions.TransactionFailureException:
>   Transaction rolled back even if marked as successful

Below are some information regarding how I am doing.

```
@Procedure("example.search12")
public Stream<SearchHit> searchData(
    @Name("phoneNumber") String phoneNumber, 
    @Name("searchText") String searchText) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {

    List<SearchHit> resultList = new ArrayList<>();
    try {
        Node startNode = getStartNode(phoneNumber);
        if(null == startNode){
            System.out.println("Phone Number not found::"+ phoneNumber);
            return null;
        }
        final Set<Node> results = new LinkedHashSet<>();
        innerSeacrh(db, startNode, searchText, 1,results);
        List<Node> nodes = new ArrayList<Node>();

        for (Node node : results) {
            System.out.println(node.getProperty("fullname"));
            nodes.add(node);
            resultList.add(new SearchHit(node));
        }
    } catch(Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    return resultList.stream();
}

public static class SearchHit {
    // This records contain a single field named 'nodeId'
    public long nodeId;

    public SearchHit(Node node) {
        this.nodeId = node.getId();
    }
}
```

I am calling the stored proc by below command:

```
call example.search12("919818131043","anu");
```

Getting below error.

> org.neo4j.kernel.api.exceptions.TransactionFailureException:
>   Transaction rolled back even if marked as successful

Please help i need to resolve it as soon as possible.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved this issue. Actually when we hit the stored proc it implicitly opens a transaction so if you try to open another transaction in the same thread. it gives problems.